# How to change url path wording

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, path

What I would like to accomplish is changing "domain.com/folder" to "domain.com/shop" and all contents that is being accessed in the "folder" directory is displayed in "domain.com/shop".

From: domain.com/folder/cart

TO: domain.com/shop/cart

To further explain this I want the folder name to automatically change to "shop". I tried to do this using another helpful page that had the similar issue but I was faced with a 404 page when typing in domain.com/shop.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/folder(.*)?$ /shop$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/shop(.*)?$ /folder$1 [NC]
```

Shop is a non existent folder in my website files. I am hoping I do not have to create this because my software I am using is already installed in a folder and I can't just change its name to "shop" without fully breaking everything that calls for that path.

Comment: Just to clarify, so you want the user's browser window to display example.com/shop/... but you want that to map internally to example.com/folder/... for the sake of back-end logic?

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite can only rewrite/redirect requested URIs. So you would need to request /shop/… to get it rewritten to a corresponding /folder/….

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*) folder/$1
```

Comment: Also worth nothing that the rewrite rule should place the slash after "shop" outside of the .* catch-all like Udit does in his answer. Otherwise you'll also be accidentally mapping "shopping" or "shop-bad-things-you-probably-dont-want" with that rule as well.

Comment: It worked but just wish I can fully change any calls for “folder” in the url to just shop even if a link is pointed at that folder. Like it automatically changes to shop. I know something like that might not seem possible.